# Find the limit of the sequence $(b_n)^\infty _{n=1}$ where $b_n$ is the integral from $-2\pi n$ to $\pi + 2\pi n$ of $x\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am struggling to complete this question. I know that the function is symmetrical, so the integral from $-n$ to $n$ of $x\cos(x)$ is just 0. but this has an additional $\pi$. I tried splitting up the integral to two, one going from $-2\pi n$ to $2\pi n$ and another from $2\pi n$ to $2\pi n + \pi$ and that just doesn't work, its just as hard to solve. Is the only way to just solve normally? It just will be a very very long process so I am suspicious.

Comment: Integrate by parts. $\int x \cos x dx =x \sin x -\int \sin x+C$.

Comment: What's so hard in computing $\int x\cos(x)\mathrm{d}x$?

Comment: Its the fact that it is evaluated from the bounds, it just means there is a lot more working than i feel there should be. Can I in no way take advantage of the fact that this function is symmetrical along y=x?

Comment: The integral between $-2\pi n$ and $2\pi n$ is zero since the function is odd. For the last part you can use integration by parts (also for the first one though, but it is not required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\int _{a}^bx\cos(x)dx=
a\sin(a)-\cos(a)-(b\sin(b)-\cos(b)$) which can be derived by integration by parts and then using the fundamental theorem of calculus .